# Бэггинг, Стекинг и Бустниг на нескольких машинах

Tags: алгоритм, машинное-обучение, big-data, hadoop

Подскажите, как организовать, например, бэггиг (или, возможно, бустинг) на нескольких машинах? Хотелось бы понять как это делают в двух сценариях:

- все данные лежат на одной машине, но в вычислительных мощностей есть в размере k машин
- все данные лежат на кластере из k машин, например, в HBase.

Сюда же вопрос о том, стекает ли кто на нескольких машинах и как, если да?

Comment: Ну это уже какой-то Map-Reduce нужен в сторону Hadoop, Spark и т.д. Если не так масштабно, то Dask умеет на кластере машин работать, но я особо не разбирался с таким вариантом.